# 24vdc current boost?

Tags: capacitor-charging

I have a access control system that applies 24vdc to a solenoid to unlock a door. The power supply is 24vdc 16a inrush, 1a constant. Due to the wire size and distance it doesn't always pull it completely in. Is there a capacitor circuit that could be built at the solenoid end that would "help" with the initial current inrush, then charge up again while the current is holding the solenoid open? Maybe grasping at straws, but this looks to be the site that would know which straw! Mainly looking to see if this is even possible before subsequently trying to figure out the how. Thanks!

Comment: probably not with only two wires....

Comment: Maybe - depends on how your wiring runs. Can you add a drawing showing what runs where?

Comment: oiling the actuator and sanding the holes can fix marginal operation. a capacitor could help, but you need a big one at 35v. it's hard to say how big, i would start with a cheap 4400uf and see if it helps at all. i would tweak the mechanics as much as possible first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct, you are going to want a capacitor near the coil to provide the initial large current spike needed to drive it. This is a decoupling capacitors job in many other applications and is no different here. This should function as you describe, A similar circuit is used to drive pneumatic solenoids in paintball guns. pull the gate of M2 low to charge the cap, once it has been given enough time to charge up, then pull the gate of M4 low, this will shove current through the coil and allow it to close. This will decouple the solenoid from the power supply. M2 may also be omitted. And also be sure that the gates are biased with a resistor to the source voltage (24V) so when it is pulled low the mosfet will actually turn on. This is nothing but a rough sketch and may need other support circuitry for robustness, so I would read up on driving inductive loads and solenoids in genral. Hope this helps!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMc9eI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>